# How can I Add knockback to an tagged entity relative to where they're looking?

Tags: javascript, minecraft

I need to know how go apply knockback to an entity relative to where they are looking or where their coordinates are rather than using the world's coordinates. I am on Minecraft Bedrock edition Version 1.20.1

Here is the code I'm using that works.

```
console.warn(`test script running`);

world.events.tick.subscribe(() => {
    for (const entity of world.getDimension("overworld").getEntities()) {
        if (!entity.hasTag("test") == true) continue;
        entity.applyKnockback(0 , 0 , 0 , 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. I suggest you to add some tag as the langage use and check for the library you're using if it has a tag for example